# How to check whether the inner object exists or not in react native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Recently I am doing project on react-native. But I am facing a chilly problem. When I call API sometimes I get inner object, but in few case I didn't get inner object. Json format is like

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "response": {
        "player": {
            "pid": 43332,
            "title": "Abdur Razzak",
            "short_name": "Abdur Razzak",
            "first_name": "Abdur",
            "last_name": "Razzak",
            "middle_name": "",
            "birthdate": "1982-06-15",
            "birthplace": "",
            "country": "bd"
        },
        "batting": {
            "test": {
                "matches": 13,
                "innings": 22,
                "notout": 6,
                 ........
            },
            "odi": {
                "match_id": 0,
                "inning_id": 0,
                "matches": 153,
                ..............
            },
            "t20i": {
                "match_id": 0,
                "inning_id": 0,
                "matches": 34,
                "innings": 20,
                "notout": 10,
                 .......
            },
            "t20": {
                "match_id": 0,
                "inning_id": 0,
                "matches": 87,
                "innings": 43,
                "notout": 18,
                .......
            },
        }
}
```

But sometimes for few player I didn't get inner object

```
          "t20i": {
                    "match_id": 0,
                    "inning_id": 0,
                    "matches": 34,
                    "innings": 20,
                    "notout": 10,
                    "runs": 41,
                    "balls": 74,
                    "highest": "9",
                    ........
                }
```

Because of this problem I get error when I write code to show value of `t20i` properties. So that I needed to check first whether this inner object is exist or not. My react-native code is given below. In this section I am consuming json object by calling api.

```
export default class ProfileDetails extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        navigation: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            matchObject: null,
            loading: true,
            upperBanner: "",
            lowerBanner: ""
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        AsyncStorage.getItem("user")
            .then(response => {
                //alert(JSON.stringify(response))
                const x = JSON.parse(response);

                this.axiosGetRecentMatchDetails(
                    `http://206.189.159.149:8080/com-sweetitech-tigers-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/api/match/player/profile?access_token=${
                        x.access_token
                        }&client_id=android-client&client_secret=android-secret&id=${
                        this.props.navigation.state.params.pid
                        }`
                );
                axios
                    .get(
                        `http://206.189.159.149:8080/com-sweetitech-tigers-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/api/banner/specific?access_token=${
                            x.access_token
                            }&client_id=android-client&client_secret=android-secret&pageNumber=10&position=1`
                    )
                    .then(banner => {
                        console.log(banner);
                        this.setState({
                            upperBanner: banner.data.image.url
                        });
                    });
                axios
                    .get(
                        `http://206.189.159.149:8080/com-sweetitech-tigers-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/api/banner/specific?access_token=${
                            x.access_token
                            }&client_id=android-client&client_secret=android-secret&pageNumber=10&position=2`
                    )
                    .then(banner => {
                        console.log(banner);
                        this.setState({
                            lowerBanner: banner.data.image.url
                        });
                    });

            })
            .catch(() => {
                Alert.alert(
                    "Cannot connect to internal storage, make sure you have the correct storage rights."
                );
            });
    }

    axiosGetRecentMatchDetails = async urlvariable => {
        axios
            .get(urlvariable)
            .then(response => {
                this.setState(
                    {
                        matchObject: response.data
                    },

                    () => {
                        this.setState({
                            loading: false
                        });
                    }
                );

            })
            .catch(error => {
                if (error.response.status === 401) {
                    getuserdetails()
                        .then(res => {
                            this.setState({}, () => {
                                this.axiosGetRecentMatchDetails(
                                    `http://206.189.159.149:8080/com-sweetitech-tigers-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/api/match/player/profile?access_token=${
                                        res.access_token
                                        }&client_id=android-client&client_secret=android-secret&id=${
                                        this.props.navigation.state.params.pid
                                        }`
                                );
                            });
                        })
                        .catch(() => {
                            this.setState({
                                loading: false
                            });
                            Alert.alert(
                                "you are being logged out for unavilability, Please log in again!"
                            );
                            this.props.navigation.navigate("LoginPage");
                        });
                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        loading: false
                    });
                }
            });
    };
```

Using this section I print property of inner object.

```
                     <View
                        style={{
                            flexDirection: "row",
                            paddingTop: 6,
                            paddingBottom: 6,
                            borderTopWidth: 1,
                            borderBottomWidth: 1,
                            borderColor: "#dcdcdc"
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.leftRow}>ODIs</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.odi.matches}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.odi.innings}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.odi.runs}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.odi.highest}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.odi.run100}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.odi.run50}</Text>
                    </View>

                    <View
                        style={{
                            flexDirection: "row",
                            paddingTop: 6,
                            paddingBottom: 6,
                            borderTopWidth: 1,
                            borderBottomWidth: 1,
                            borderColor: "#dcdcdc"
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.leftRow}>T20Is</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.t20i.matches}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.t20i.innings}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.t20i.runs}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.t20i.highest}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.t20i.run100}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.t20i.run50}</Text>
                    </View>
```

But the problem is sometimes I don't get inner object `t20i`. So that I get get error while printing `<Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.t20i.matches}</Text>` .So I need a conditional check whether the inner object `t20i` exist or not. I tried several condition but failed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you store your entire response in `state` ?

Comment: Yes, Stored in `matchObject` object !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your last `<View>` element I guess that is the element responsible for `t20i` property of your `state` ?

```
    <View 
style={{ flexDirection: "row", paddingTop: 6, paddingBottom: 6, borderTopWidth: 1, borderBottomWidth: 1, borderColor: "#dcdcdc" }} > 
<Text style={styles.leftRow}>T20Is</Text> 
<Text style={styles.rowElementText}{this.state.matchObject.batting.t20i.matches}</Text> 
<Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.t20i.innings}</Text> 
<Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.t20i.runs}</Text> 
<Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.t20i.highest}</Text> 
<Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.t20i.run100}</Text> 
<Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.t20i.run50}</Text> </View>
```

Can you make this a separate functional Component that returns this specific portion using conditional rendering? Like below

```
    const t20iComponent = () => { return (<View 
style={{ flexDirection: "row", paddingTop: 6, paddingBottom: 6, borderTopWidth: 1, borderBottomWidth: 1, borderColor: "#dcdcdc" }} > 
<Text style={styles.leftRow}>T20Is</Text> 
<Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.t20i.matches}</Text> 
<Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.t20i.innings}</Text> 
<Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.t20i.runs}</Text> 
<Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.t20i.highest}</Text> 
<Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.t20i.run100}</Text> 
<Text style={styles.rowElementText}>{this.state.matchObject.batting.t20i.run50}</Text> 
</View> ); }
```

And conditional rendering in where you will going to apply this function

```
this.state.matchObject.batting.t20i ? t20iComponent ():null
```

Thus it will only render that view if that `state` property exists otherwise returns `null`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, I will let you know after checking !

Comment: Your condition helped me brother !

Comment: Glad to help you brother 

Answer (score 1):

Whether than repeating the same component with not knowing the property on the object is there or not, you can simplify your code while checking if the property is there or not. To do this you can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

**Sample**

```
  <View>
    {Object.keys(this.state.matchObject.batting).map(key => (
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          paddingTop: 6,
          paddingBottom: 6,
          borderTopWidth: 1,
          borderBottomWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#dcdcdc',
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.leftRow}>{key.toUpperCase()}</Text>
        {Object.keys(this.state.matchObject.batting[key]).map(key2 => (
          <Text style={styles.rowElementText}>
            {this.state.matchObject.batting[key][key2]}
          </Text>
        ))}
      </View>
    ))}
  </View>
```